# MongoDB How can I use aggregate instead for the following query

Tags: mongodb

Am trying to find the total amount of entries within a database. How can produce the same result using aggregate instead for the query shown below:

```
db.Subject.find({"subject": {$exists:true}}).count()
```

I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run

```
db.Subject.aggregate({$match:{subject:{$exists:true}}}).itcount()
```

Or

```
db.Subject.aggregate([{$match:{subject:{$exists:true}}},{$count:"result"}])
```

- `$match` uses exactly the same syntax than find.
- `itcount()` is a cursor method, and it's normally [preferred over `count()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/#cursor.count).
- `$count` is a stage, meaning that it receives the output of `$match`, and it involves two stages under the hood, `$group` and `$project`
- The result is equivalent, just more flexible using `$count`

Comment: May I know what's the difference between both?

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent, but `$count` let you give a name to the result, and you get `{result:"number"}` @Frio_Penitencia

Comment: Oh okok. Thx for the explanation, have only just started learning about aggregate.

Comment: No worries. Remember this: find and $match use same stuff. But the rest of "stages" are a little different. @Frio_Penitencia

Comment: @Frio_Penitencia added a few details for you.

Comment: Thank you for going into such detail for your explanation!

Comment: Are there like specific scenarios where you would use itcount instead of count and vice versa?

Comment: @Frio_Penitencia I've never fall into one, but `count()` reads from metadata, this means that if the cluster didn't yet update the metadata, `count()` can differ from the real number of documents. Metadata reads happen if you run something like `db.coll.find().count()`

Comment: @Frio_Penitencia If you run `db.collName.find().itcount` and `db.collName.find().count` you'll find the function's definition, and they seem to be pretty different.